# T-SQL Move From Test To Production Dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

GOAL: 
Pass in two parameters (a task and a primary key) to generate a list of tables. Take the list, and then dynamically construct insert statements with the aim to copy data from a production environment to a test environment. In other words, do programmatically what 'EDIT TOP 200' does...but a lot faster.

PROBLEM: The query spins and runs indefinitely. There should only be about 20-30 tables that the query will need to construct insert statements for...so I let it go for about 2 minutes before concluding that I probably have an infinite loop somewhere. Note that I'm not even inserting anything into the test database at this point.

At the moment I'm just trying to display the VALUES portion of the insert statements using the RAISERROR call. While the endgame isn't implemented, I'm hoping someone can help me figure out the problem.

Thus far:

```
USE MAINDB
DECLARE @PK int = 1000,
 @TaskName nvarchar(50) = 'TASK', 
 @curTable nvarchar(75),
 @curRow nvarchar(75),
 @tmpStatement nvarchar(500),
 @tmpInsert nvarchar(500)

RAISERROR('Retrieving Tables',0,1) WITH NOWAIT
 DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR 

    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 PRMPTTBL.tTable as PromptTable
       FROM THING1 TK INNER JOIN THING2 SC ON TK.tkNo=SC.tkNo
              INNER JOIN Component EL on EL.scNo=SC.scNo             
              LEFT OUTER JOIN Field FLD1 on FLD1.cfNo=EL.cfNoPrompt1            
              LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTableTable MTTTBL on MTTTBL.tbNo=FLD1.tbNo

       WHERE EL.CustNo=@Custno
              AND (MTTTBL.tTable is not NULL AND MTTTBL.tTable not in('OneTableIDontWant'))
              AND MTTTBL.tTable not like '%[_]d%' --eliminate any tables that are actually views
              AND EL.cfNo > 0  
              AND TK.Description like @TaskName

RAISERROR('Table',0,1) WITH NOWAIT
OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @curTable
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   SET @tmpStatement = 'SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [MYCONN].TEST_MYDB.dbo.' + @curTable + ' where PK=' + Cast(@PK as nvarchar(10))
   EXEC (@tmpStatement)

   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
   BEGIN
        DECLARE RowCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM REALDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @curTable

        RAISERROR('Row',0,1) WITH NOWAIT
        OPEN RowCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM RowCursor INTO @curRow
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
          SET @tmpInsert = @tmpInsert + ',' + @curRow
        END

        IF RIGHT(@tmpInsert,1) = ',' SET @tmpInsert = LEFT(@tmpInsert,LEN(@tmpInsert) -1)
        RAISERROR(@tmpInsert,0,1) WITH NOWAIT

        CLOSE RowCursor
        DEALLOCATE RowCursor
        SET @tmpInsert = ''
        FETCH NEXT FROM RowCursor INTO @curRow
   END


   FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @curTable
END

CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

Comment: did you run your SQL statement separately to make sure it works the way you intend?

Comment: Yes. The initial SELECT retrieves the intended tables. From my Messages window I see that it enters the 'Row' section exactly once before hanging up (hence why I think it's stuck in a loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      SET @tmpInsert = @tmpInsert + ',' + @curRow
    END
```

is an infinite loop, because you don't `FETCH NEXT` inside it.