# T-SQL Move From Test To Production Dynamically (Part 2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Alright, since my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372063/t-sql-move-from-test-to-production-dynamically), I was able to make progress!! However, I've run into another problem...once again:

GOAL: Pass in two parameters (a task and a primary key) to generate a list of tables. Take the list, and then dynamically construct insert statements with the aim to copy data from a production environment to a test environment. In other words, do programmatically what 'EDIT TOP 200' does...but a lot faster.

PROBLEM (UPDATED): @tmpInserVars isn't updating with each iteration. It gets set the first time the code is entered, and never refreshes.

Thus far:

```
USE MAINDB
DECLARE @PK int = 1000,
 @TaskName nvarchar(50) = 'TASK', 
 @curTable nvarchar(75),
 @curRow nvarchar(75),
 @tmpStatement nvarchar(500),
 @tmpInsert nvarchar(500)

RAISERROR('Retrieving Tables',0,1) WITH NOWAIT
 DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR 

    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 PRMPTTBL.tTable as PromptTable
       FROM THING1 TK INNER JOIN THING2 SC ON TK.tkNo=SC.tkNo
              INNER JOIN Component EL on EL.scNo=SC.scNo             
              LEFT OUTER JOIN Field FLD1 on FLD1.cfNo=EL.cfNoPrompt1            
              LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTableTable MTTTBL on MTTTBL.tbNo=FLD1.tbNo

       WHERE EL.PK=@PK
              AND (MTTTBL.tTable is not NULL AND MTTTBL.tTable not in('OneTableIDontWant'))
              AND MTTTBL.tTable not like '%[_]d%' --eliminate any tables that are actually views
              AND EL.cfNo > 0  
              AND TK.Description like @TaskName

RAISERROR('Table',0,1) WITH NOWAIT
OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @curTable
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   SET @tmpStatement = 'SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [MYCONN].TEST_MYDB.dbo.' + @curTable + ' where PK=' + Cast(@PK as nvarchar(10))
   EXEC (@tmpStatement)
   RAISERROR(N'Table (outside): %s',0,1,@curTable) WITH NOWAIT  

   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
   BEGIN
        --@tmpInsertVars isn't updating!!!
        RAISERROR(N'Initial Select: %s',0,1,@tmpStatement) WITH NOWAIT
        SELECT @tmpInsertVars = COALESCE(@tmpInsertVars + ',','') + COLUMN_NAME 
        FROM PRODDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @curTable

        SET @tmpInsertStatement = 'INSERT INTO [MYCONN].TEST_MYDB.dbo.' + @curTable + ' (' + @tmpInsertVars + ')' +
                                  ' SELECT TOP 500 ' + @tmpInsertVars +
                                  ' FROM TEST_MYDB.' + @curTable +
                                  ' WHERE PK=' + Cast(@PK as nvarchar(10))

        RAISERROR(N'Insert Statement: %s',0,1,@tmpInsertStatement) WITH NOWAIT
   END


   FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @curTable
END

CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare your @tmpInsertStatement and @tmpInsertVars variables.
2. Reset @tmpInsertVars to NULL just before you populate it

   ```
   USE MAINDB
   DECLARE @PK int = 1000,
    @TaskName nvarchar(50) = 'TASK', 
    @curTable nvarchar(75),
    @curRow nvarchar(75),
    @tmpStatement nvarchar(500),
    @tmpInsert nvarchar(500),
    @tmpInsertStatement nvarchar(500),
    @tmpInsertVars nvarchar(500)

   RAISERROR('Retrieving Tables',0,1) WITH NOWAIT
    DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR 

       SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 PRMPTTBL.tTable as PromptTable
          FROM THING1 TK INNER JOIN THING2 SC ON TK.tkNo=SC.tkNo
                 INNER JOIN Component EL on EL.scNo=SC.scNo             
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN Field FLD1 on FLD1.cfNo=EL.cfNoPrompt1            
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTableTable MTTTBL on MTTTBL.tbNo=FLD1.tbNo

          WHERE EL.PK=@PK
                 AND (MTTTBL.tTable is not NULL AND MTTTBL.tTable not in('OneTableIDontWant'))
                 AND MTTTBL.tTable not like '%[_]d%' --eliminate any tables that are actually views
                 AND EL.cfNo > 0  
                 AND TK.Description like @TaskName

   RAISERROR('Table',0,1) WITH NOWAIT
   OPEN TableCursor
   FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @curTable
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      SET @tmpStatement = 'SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [MYCONN].TEST_MYDB.dbo.' + @curTable + ' where PK=' + Cast(@PK as nvarchar(10))
      EXEC (@tmpStatement)
      RAISERROR(N'Table (outside): %s',0,1,@curTable) WITH NOWAIT  

      IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
      BEGIN
           --@tmpInsertVars isn't updating!!!
           SELECT @tmpInsertVars = NULL; -- RESET @tmpInsertVars
           RAISERROR(N'Initial Select: %s',0,1,@tmpStatement) WITH NOWAIT
           SELECT @tmpInsertVars = COALESCE(@tmpInsertVars + ',','') + COLUMN_NAME 
           FROM PRODDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = @curTable

           SET @tmpInsertStatement = 'INSERT INTO [MYCONN].TEST_MYDB.dbo.' + @curTable + ' (' + @tmpInsertVars + ')' +
                                     ' SELECT TOP 500 ' + @tmpInsertVars +
                                     ' FROM TEST_MYDB.' + @curTable +
                                     ' WHERE PK=' + Cast(@PK as nvarchar(10))

           RAISERROR(N'Insert Statement: %s',0,1,@tmpInsertStatement) WITH NOWAIT
      END


      FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @curTable
   END

   CLOSE TableCursor
   DEALLOCATE TableCursor
   ```

Comment: Wow. Thank you SO much!! Would you mind telling me why this works? To me, I think of the "SELECT @tmpInsertVars = COALESCE(---)" as reassigning the value with each iteration when clearly this is not the case.

Comment: The tmpInsertVars variable will continue to retain its value in subsequent loops since the assignment statement is just appending to it.  COALESCE just takes the first non-null value it can find in its arguments.  On each subsequent loop it still has a non-null value from the last iteration, so the first argument in the COALESCE statement kicks in to retain the existing data and begin appending more data.  By resetting tmpInsertVars back to NULL before the COALESCE, you are ensuring that the first argument/expression will be NULL since (NULL + ',') = NULL.